# 'Da "attenzionare" a "sabotaggia" il passo è breve, ma la caduta rovinosa'

Tags: grammar

Dopo che Davide Serra, Founder & CEO Algebris investments | Asset Manager focused Global Financials / Equity and Credit / UK-USA-Singapore, nonché noto consigliere economico, ha usato la parola 'sabotaggia', potrebbe questa diventare una parola di uso corrente?

[image]

Ho notato che qualcuno ha commentato 'Da "attenzionare" a "sabotaggia" il passo è breve, ma la caduta rovinosa'. Cosa ne pensate?

Comment: While "*attenzionare*" is ok ([1](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/verbo-attenzionare), [2](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/parole/attenzionare.html), [3](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/attenzionare.shtml)), what's the need of "*sabotaggiare*" if we can use "*sabotare*"? Are we sure it is not just a mistake?

Comment: Benchè possa essere d'accordo sul fatto che *sabota* non sia la forma verbale più utilizzata a questo mondo, *sabotaggia* è ancor più brutto e, ovviamente, non è italiano. Avrebbe potuto evitare la `e` di troppo ed usare `boicotta`, che suona decisamente meglio.

Comment: Se è per questo, il fatto che “sé” non voglia l'accento in “sé stesso” è una leggenda urbana ( http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/se/ ).

Comment: Speriamo proprio di no! ;-)

Comment: Dove sono gli articoli in questo tweet!!!

Comment: tutto il tweet è incomprensibile (e sì, qua non mettere l'accento su "sé stessa" **peggiora** la comprensione della frase

Comment: Eh, gli articoli. Ho persino protestato a "La Repubblica", sono stato bellamente ignorato. Leggere la prima pagina del suddetto sito internet fa venir male, a volte...

Comment: Penso che è rimasto troppo tempo a in UK o a Singapore e si è dimenticato l'italiano.

Answer (score 9):

Il testo ha vari errori grammaticali (mancano articoli ed accenti, il doppio "e" suona malissimo), non credo che dovrebbe essere preso come spunto da nessuno per coniare parole nuove.

Attenzionare mi sembra bruttissimo, però ha una funzione e un origine differenti a parer mio.
- La forma verbale di "attenzione" non esiste, quidi attenzionare potrebbe colmare una necessità verbale.
- Sabotaggio ha già una forma verbale corretta che è tra l'altro esteticamente migliore.
- Sabotaggio-Sabotare viene dal francese Sabotage-saboter, la parola entrò nella lingua italiana circa 200 anni fa. Sembra improbabile una involuzione del lessico dopo tanto tempo.

Comment: *Attenzionare* è brutto, burocratico e inutile. Nel linguaggio burocratico si creano verbi dove non se ne sente il bisogno: come l'*estintore carrellato* che vedo tutte le sere in stazione, o le famose *porte allarmate*. Per non dire della norma che impone alle ditte fornitrici di oggetti per la sicurezza di scrivere sulla plastica trasparente *to break in case of fire* sopra a *rompere in caso di incendio* (il burocrate guardò il dizionario e, siccome c'era *to break*, …). Si può passare sopra la mancanza di articoli, ma "sabotaggiare" indica solo ignoranza.

Comment: Per curiosità, una nota sull'[interessante etimologia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabotage#Etymology) di sabotare.

Comment: Suona forse poliziesco ma _allertare_ è corretto e anche più breve.